# AttributeError: module 'PIL' has no attribute 'Image'

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, pil, pillow

Использую библиотеку telebot(PyTelegramBot)
Пытаюсь отправить фото
[image: l]

Но выдаёт ошибку:
[image]

```
Python == 3.7.3
PyTelegramBot == 3.7.3
Pillow == 7.2.0
```

Comment: А почему у вас в коде не имопртирован метод `from PIL import Image`? Да и в следующий раз приводите код в текстовом формате, а не не с помощью фото.

Comment: @DenisRudnitskiy В этом нет нужды, ошибка возникает в самой библиотеке `PyTelegramBot`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать другую версию telebot (например, 3.7.2), у меня это сработало.